# Cambiar el hamburguer icon del drawer en Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

me gustaria sabr como cambiar el icono de las tres rallitas, que viene predeterminadamente al crear un drawer, por otro icono.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Toolbar"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.purple[200],
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
      onPressed: () => MainDrawer(),
    )
  ),
  drawer: MainDrawer(
    pressItem1: () {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return MaterialMainPage();
          },
        ),
      );
    },
    pressItem2: () {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return CupertinoMainPage();
          },
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
```

Tengo esto de momento, pero no consigo que al clicar en la flecha se despliegue el drawer. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Está bien con el `leading` como lo haces, para sobreescribir el botón de la izquierda del `AppBar`, lo que te hace falta es decirle al `Scaffold` que es el que controla el comportamiento del `Drawer`, quedaría así :

```dart
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Toolbar"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.purple[200],
    leading: Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
          onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
        );
      }
    )
  ),
```

El widget `Builder` es necesario para que pueda generar un nuevo `BuildContext`.